# SQL ms excel работа с ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1

Tags: sql, excel, vba

Я хочу получить случайные строки по определенному условию.
Есть колонки сотр, идент, алф, дата. У всех тип строка, кроме даты(дата).
Получить необходимо по каждому сотр строки, где алф = а в количестве 5%(не менее 15 и не более 25)  от общего количества строк по группировке(сотр,алф).

Пишет ошибку
"Ошибка синтаксиса (пропущен оператор) в выражении запроса 'RAND() LIMIT ...'"

```sql
SELECT [сотр] as emp,*
FROM [Лист1$A2:P]
WHERE [алф] = 'а'
GROUP BY [сотр],[идент]
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT IIF(
          ((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [Лист1$A2:P] WHERE [алф] = 'а' AND [сотр] = emp) * 0.05) < 15,15,
             IIF(
                 ((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [Лист1$A2:P] WHERE [алф] = 'а' AND [сотр] = emp) * 0.05) > 25,25,
                  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [Лист1$A2:P] WHERE [алф] = 'а' AND [сотр] = emp) * 0.05
                 )
         )
```

Подключение в VBA

```
Public Function Connect(ByVal sPath As String)
Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
   Select Case CLng(Split(Application.Version, ".")(0))
   Case Is <12
      sCon = "Provider-Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & sPath _
      & ";Extended Properties =""Excel 8.0; HDR=YES;IMEX=1"";"
   Case IS >=12
      sCon = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & sPath _
      & ";Extended Properties = ""Excel 12.0; HDR=YES;IMEX=1"";"
   End Select
cn.Open sCon
End Function

Sub Go()
*****
Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
  Connect (Thisworkbook.Path & "\" & Thisworkbook.Name)
  Set rs = cn.Execute(SQLQuery)
***
End Sub
```

SQLQuery - сам запрос, который выше.

Comment: Это... вообще... SQL-то - он где?

Comment: @Akina, этот код запускаю в vba

Comment: Простите, как именно, каким кодом? Без какой-то обвязки VBA в принципе SQL не понимает...

Comment: Не VBA. Это запрос (PQ, наверное)

Comment: @Akina,@vikttur , через adodb connection

Comment: О! Давайте ЭТОТ VBA-код. И потом - кто сказал, что ADODB понимает LIMIT? емнип он понимает TOP N...

Comment: @Akina, обновил вопрос.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. MS Jet в упор не понимает

```
SELECT .. LIMIT ..
```

Он привык к

```
SELECT TOP ...
```

2. Параметр `TOP N` должен быть литералом, а не выражением.

---

Итого: первым запросом получайте количество нужных записей, вставляйте полученное число во второй запрос, и выполняйте его.

```vba
Public Function Connect(sPath As String)
Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
   Select Case CLng(Split(Application.Version, ".")(0))
   Case Is <12
      sCon = "Provider-Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & sPath _
      & ";Extended Properties =""Excel 8.0; HDR=YES;IMEX=1"";"
   Case IS >=12
      sCon = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & sPath _
      & ";Extended Properties = ""Excel 12.0; HDR=YES;IMEX=1"";"
   End Select
cn.Open sCon
End Function
```

```vba
Sub Main()
Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
  ' *** '
  Connect Thisworkbook.FullName
  SQLQuery = "запрос для получения количества записей"
  Set rs = cn.Execute(SQLQuery)
  rs.movefirst
  cnt = rs!cnt
  rs.close
  SQLQuery = "SELECT TOP " & cnt & " хвост запроса на получение данных"
  Set rs = cn.Execute(SQLQuery)
  rs.movefirst
  ' *** '
End Sub
```

Comment: а как можно получить случайные строки?

Comment: @rozhalin Надо пробовать... насколько я помню, `ORDER BY Rnd()` в Аксессе просто игнорируется (а заодно с ним, кстати, начинает игнорироваться и TOP N) - но там DAO.

Comment: я обращаюсь к excel, при чем здесь Аксесс? Какие функции или бест практис подскажете посмотреть для случайного выбора?

Comment: *я обращаюсь к excel, при чем здесь Аксесс?* А какая разница откуда работать через VBA с DAO или там ADO? хоть из Ворда, хоть из Автокада - всё едино. *Какие функции ... посмотреть для случайного выбора?* да попробуйте `ORDER BY RND()` - а ну как ADODB пропустит.